# C#, EF: Select from table using list of tuples

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

Let's assume that I have a List of tuples with 3 properties. Now in my database, I have a Table that has 3 fields that may or may not match up with the tuples.  How on earth do I tell EF

"Select from OtherTable o where o.Prop1 = tuple.Item1 && o.Prop2 = tuple.Item2 && o.Prop3 = tuple.Item3".

I understand very well how to do this if I have a single tuple, but I don't know how to do it when I have a list of tuples and I want all the matching records from OtherTable returned.  If I was matching on a single property, I would do something like "where ListOfIds.Contains(id)...) and then go about my day but with multiple properties this approach falls apart.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how many items are there in your tuple list? If it's not to many then you can just generate a long `OR`ed query on the fly - if it's to many I would drop them into a temp. table and use a `IN` query

Comment: @Carsten There could be hundreds of tuples in my list.  I'm still looking around.  Looks like I will have to use a SProc of some kind.

Comment: hundreds are not that much - to be honest I would try using a large or-ed where - if this is not working or is to slow try the second one

Comment: Can you select all rows from table?

Comment: I would go for second approach from Slava Utesinov's answer. But it will only work if all columns involved in concatenation are `string`. If they are different datatypes, it would be required to fetch a super set of matching records from DB first, as `EF` cannot handle concatenation of other datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

What about SQL query for entity with dynamic "where" condition?

```
    var list = new List<Tuple<string, int, bool>>();
    list.Add(new Tuple<string, int, bool>("1", 2, true));
    list.Add(new Tuple<string, int, bool>("2", 4, true));
    list.Add(new Tuple<string, int, bool>("3", 5, false));

    var query = list.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperties().Select((y, index) => string.Concat("o.Prop", index + 1, "=", y.GetValue(x))).Aggregate((a, b) => a + " and " + b))
                    .Aggregate((a, b) => string.Format("({0}) or ({1})", a, b));

    var result = context.OtherTable.SqlQuery("Select * from OtherTable o where " + query).ToList();
```

OR you can use `Contains` that way (as  *wonderbell* said, it will work only if all of your o.Prop*N* have string type, but you can try to use something like [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd487158(v=vs.110).aspx) to cast another type to string):

```
    var queryList = list.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.GetValue(x).ToString())
                    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b));
    var result = context.OtherTable.Where(x => queryList.Contains(x.Prop1 + "," + x.Prop2 + "," + x.Prop3))
                    .ToList();
```